# MySQL - MariaDB - Query count words in column

Tags: mysql, count

How can I query this case:

```
Machine |   Monitors
---------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Computer 1  |   Computer Name: Dell,Model: a - Computer Name: Dell,Model: d<br>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Computer 2  |   Computer Name: Dell,Model: abcd - Computer Name: Lenovo,Model: abcd<br>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
Computer 3  |   Computer Name: SAMSUNG,Model: abcd
```

I need to convert the sum of the string "Computer Name" when it appears and get the count of it, but I don't know how!

To obtain this result:

```
Machine |   Monitors
--------------------
Computer 1  |   2
--------------------
Computer 2  |   2
--------------------
Computer 3  |   1
```

Comment: i think first of all you have to update your table architecture

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: That table is from a software called KACE, wich I needed to crete a custom inventory rule to bring those data, and now I want to filter the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some string manipulations:

```
select machine,
       (length(monitors) - length(replace(monitors, 'Computer Name:', ''))) / length('Computer Name:')
from t;
```

You *should* reconsider how you are storing this data.  Sometimes we are stuck with bad decisions by others.  But if you have a choice, you should have another table with one row per "machine" and "computer name".

Comment: It returned only 0 as numbers for quantity of monitors!

Comment: I got it! Thank you!